# $G$ is a $p$-group and $N$ a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, p-groups

Let's say $G$ is a $p$-group so that $|G|=p^{r}$ for $p$ prime and $r>1$. Let say $N\subset G$ a subgroup with $|N|=p$. I'm trying to prove that $N$ is contained in the center ($Z(G)=\{a\in G\mid xa=ax, \forall x\in G\}$) of $G$ if and only if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I have a proof but I got the hint that I needed to look at the conjugacy classes of $N$ and I didn't use that, but I can't find my mistake.

1. So first  assume that $N \subset Z(G)$. Let's take $g\in G$ random and $n \in N$ random. Now will follow because $N\subset Z(G)$ that $gn=ng$. So $gng^{-1}=n$ $\in N$ This implies that $N$ is a normal subgroup.
2. Now I assume that $N$ is a normal subgroup. I wanted to do exact the same thing as above but in the other direction. I think I forget something or do it wrong.

Can someone maybe help and tell me why I need to use that $G$ is a $p$-group.

EDIT: It's wasn't clear what i meant with that I wanted to do exact the same thing for the other direction.
So i thougt that if we know that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ That we could say: $\forall g\in G, \forall n\in N: gng^{-1}\in N$.
I took a random $n\in N$. Because $N$ is an normal subgroup of $G$ is $n\in G$. Now we need to prove that $\forall x\in G: xn=nx$.
So $xnx^{-1}\in N$ because that $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ So there exist an $n_{0}\in N $ so that $xnx^{1}=n_{0}$. So $xn$=$n_{0}x$. I thought this was enough?

Comment: The group $S_3$ has a normal subgroup of order $3$ that is not in the centre. So you do need to use that $G$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: Yeah i already thought that was my fault because it's weird to not use something that's given. The problem is that I don't see in my proof were it went wrong and how to use that.

Comment: Central subgroups are normal. That is always true. But you didn't actually write down the converse, so that's where your problem is.

Comment: wait I don't understand you. Yes a central subgroup is normal. But what do you mean by the converse?

Comment: You want to prove a normal subgroup is central. But you didn't write this in your post. For this you need that $G$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: I will edit it how i did it. Is the other way correct?

Comment: I could not make any sense of the first paragraph of your post (and I am surprised that other people apparently did). First you assumed that $N$ was a normal subgroup of order $p$  and then said you wanted to prove some condition if and only if $N$ is a normal subgroup. Secondly, the condition you are trying to prove is manifestly false, because $Z(G)$ could be larger than $N$.

Comment: I'm just trying to prove to implications. In the first implication I assume 3 things:1) G is a p group 2) N is a supbroup of G, but i think that maybe my translation is wrong in dutch we say " een normale deelgroep" but i think that a normal sharper means a normal subroup but i'm not sure 3) i assume that N is a part of the center in G

Comment: I want to prove in 1 that N is a normal sharper of G, en the second time i asume 1) and 2) and i assume 3) that N is a normal sharper of G and now i want to prove that N is a part of the center of G

Comment: I think you couldn't make sense out of it because someone edited my post but didn't really understand what i meant i think

Comment: I think i edited correctly now so i hope you can understand it

Comment: That's not enough because $n_0$ needs to be $n$ for the subgroup to be central. You need to use that $G$ is a $p$-group, because I have given you a counterexample for $G$ not a $p$-group.

Comment: So i need to prove that n=$n_{0}$ and i need to use that G is a p-group? i will try and edit my solution. Is the first thing correct ?

Comment: Yes that's fine, but that's absolutely clear. It's the other direction that has content.

Comment: It is still not quite right. But I will edit it.

Comment: I really have no clue how to use it. I tried different things that are given but I just can't find the right way, someone who can give another hint?

Comment: @mathmath: If you’ve seen the proof that a finite $p$-group must have nontrivial center, try doing something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every normal subgroup of a nilpotent group has a nontrivial intersection with the center (induction on the length of the upper central series). Since a group of prime order has exactly two subgroups, the statement follows.

Now using conjugacy classes. Take an element $x\in N$, then the conjugacy class $C_x$ of $x$ in the whole group $G$ must have order dividing $p^n$, so it is a power of $p$. On the other hand $|C_x|\le p-1$ since $N$ is normal. Hence $|C_x|=1$ and $N$ is in the center.

Comment: How do you know dat a group of prime order has  exactly two subbgroups ?

Comment: By Lagrange theorem: the order of a subgroup is $1$ or $p$.

Comment: Oh so you mean that there is a subgroup with order p and one with order 1? And that's {e} and N?

Comment: Yes, there is only one subgroup of order $1$ and only one subgroup of order $|N|$ in any finite group $N$.

Comment: the only thing i don't get is why |$C_{x}$|<p-1 because of the normal group?

Comment: Because it is inside $N$, the order of $N$ is $p$ and $C_x$ does not contain 1 unless $x=1$.